# Get Checked-Data from Check List Using ng-repet in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got undefined push error  in console

this is my html code

```
 <tr ng-repeat="row in data" ng-click="showDetails(row)">
         <td data-title="'Choose Cars'">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-modal="checkedCar" ng-checked="exists(row, selected)" ng-click="toggle(row, selected)"></td>
```

```
$scope.toggle = function (row, list) {
        var idx = list.indexOf(row);
        if (idx > -1) {
          $scope.list.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        else {
          $scope.list.push(row);

        }
      };
```

Comment: where  is the $scope.exists function@ moses

Comment: `ng-modal="checkedCar"` *typo alert* ??

Comment: what error exactly you have? when do you have that error - during rendering or when you click? Please provide small plunker example illustrating your problem. Otherwise it is un-debuggable.